# Feedback on LZSS implementation

Tags: haskell, compression

Recently, I've been trying to get back into Haskell, so I tried coding up a [LZSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Storer%E2%80%93Szymanski) implementation. I realize this is much more easily implemented imperatively, but I wanted to challenge myself. The last time I tried doing this was back in my Functional Programming class and it went poorly. It worked, but the compression was extremely slow and I was only using prelude Lists and ByteStrings. So, my goal this time around was to make something faster and memory efficient while also still being Haskell code.

This implementation of the algorithm is based off of one I found in an old 16-bit Sega Genesis game. It goes as follows: The data length is one byte with the sign bit indicating repeated data, meaning  a length of 127 bytes (plus one). The repeated data length gets converted to its positive representation. If the sign bit is set, then the next byte is the lookback offset meaning a 256 byte window.  Otherwise, the following bytes are literal data.

My questions are: What can I do to improve memory/speed performance? How easy is my code to follow?  What could I do to make my code more idiomatically Haskell?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, PatternSynonyms #-}

module Lib (
    compress,
    uncompress
) where

import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Data.Bits (Bits,complement)
import Data.Int (Int8)
import Data.List (unfoldr, null)
import Data.Monoid ((<>),mconcat,mempty)
import Data.Word (Word8)
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL (toStrict)
import Data.ByteString.Builder
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as V
import Data.Vector.Storable.ByteString
import Foreign.Storable(sizeOf)
import Numeric (showHex)

infixr 5 :<
pattern b :< bs <- (B.uncons -> Just (b, bs))
pattern Empty   <- (B.uncons -> Nothing)

prettyPrint :: B.ByteString -> String
prettyPrint = B.foldr showHex ""

signed :: Word8
signed = 0x80

breakEven :: Int
breakEven = fromIntegral $ 2 * sizeOf maxWord8

maxInt8 = maxBound::Int8
maxWord8 = maxBound::Word8

maxLength :: Int
maxLength = fromIntegral maxInt8 + 1

maxOffset :: Int
maxOffset = fromIntegral maxWord8

twosComplement :: (Bits a, Integral a) => a -> a
twosComplement a = 1 + complement a

uncompress :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
uncompress bs = uncompress' bs V.empty

uncompress' :: B.ByteString -> V.Vector Word8 -> B.ByteString
uncompress' Empty vs = vectorToByteString vs
uncompress' (b :< bs) vs
    | b > signed = let
        l = fromIntegral $ (twosComplement b) + 1
        o = fromIntegral $ B.head bs
        rs = V.slice (V.length vs - o) (min l o) vs
        rss = if l > o then V.fromList $ take (l - o) $ concat $ repeat $ V.toList rs else V.empty
        in uncompress' (B.tail bs) (vs V.++ rs V.++ rss)
    | otherwise = let
        t = fromIntegral b + 1
        in uncompress' (B.drop t bs) (vs V.++ (byteStringToVector $ B.take t bs))

compress :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
compress bs = BL.toStrict $ toLazyByteString $ compress' (byteStringToVector bs) 0 B.empty

compress' :: V.Vector Word8 -> Int -> B.ByteString -> Builder
compress' bs i ns
    | endOfData = literalData
    | literalDataLength == maxLength = flushBuffer
    | i == 0 || repeatNotLongEnough = checkNextPosition
    | otherwise = lz77Block
    where
        endOfData = i == V.length bs
        flushBuffer = literalData <> compress' bs i B.empty
        literalData = if B.null ns then mempty else (word8 (fromIntegral literalDataLength - 1)) <> byteString ns
        literalDataLength = B.length ns
        repeatNotLongEnough = not (B.null ns) && maxRepeated <= breakEven || maxRepeated < breakEven
        maxRepeated = fst optimalLength
        optimalLength = maximum $ parMap rpar (offsetMatchLength bs i) [i - o | o <- [1..maxOffset], i - o >= 0]
        checkNextPosition = compress' bs (i + 1) (B.snoc ns (bs V.! i))
        lz77Block = literalData <> repeatedData <> compress' bs (i + repeatLength) B.empty
        repeatLength = maxRepeated - if repeatRemainder < breakEven then repeatRemainder else 0
        repeatRemainder = maxRepeated `mod` maxLength
        optimalOffset = word8 $ fromIntegral $ snd optimalLength
        repeatedData = mconcat $ unfoldr (\r ->
            if r < breakEven then Nothing
            else Just (
                (word8 $ fromIntegral $ twosComplement $ (min r maxLength) - 1) <> optimalOffset,
                r - maxLength
                )
            ) maxRepeated

offsetMatchLength :: V.Vector Word8 -> Int -> Int -> (Int,Int)
offsetMatchLength bs c l = (V.length $ V.takeWhile (\a -> a) $ V.zipWith (==) (V.drop l bs) (V.drop c bs), l)
```